# Linq to SQl query performance

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQl to query the data. When I write a select query with order by and monitor in SQL Server Profiler it run the select command 2 times

1. to Select the fields from the table
2. to order the data.

It takes time when the data is huge. Is there any solution for this.

**Updated:**

```
from dc in dataContext.UserTable join 
m in dataContext.MonthLookups on dc.Month equals m.Month into sr 
from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty() 
order by dc.UserName, dc.FirstName 
select new {dc, sr.MothName};
```

**Updated:**

```
SELECT 
 [Project1].[ UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project1].[ FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project1].[ MonthName] AS [MonthName], 
[Project1].[year] AS [year]
FROM ( SELECT 
     [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[year] AS [year], 
     [Extent2].[MonthName] AS [MonthName]
    FROM  [dbo].[DutySavingFin] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MonthLookup] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Month] = [Extent2].[Month]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[UserName] ASC, [Project1].[FirstName] ASC
```

**Updated :**

Preferred way :

```
SELECT 
     [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[year] AS [year], 
     [Extent2].[MonthName] AS [MonthName]
    FROM  [dbo].[DutySavingFin] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MonthLookup] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Month] = [Extent2].[Month]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[UserName] ASC, [Extent1].[FirstName] ASC
```

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: from dc in dataContext.UserTable
                           join m in dataContext.MonthLookups on dc.Month equals m.Month into sr
                           from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
order by dc.UserName, dc.FirstName
                           select  new {dc, sr.MothName};

Comment: please edit your question and use a code block and will be a lot easier to read ;)

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling this twice somewhere (possibly implementing paging somewhere else?)

Comment: To speedup your query you can setup indexes on the columns you want to sort. it also helps to lower the amount of rows using a where statement (including indexes on those params) and sort the data after.

Comment: And btw: I am not used to LINQ/SQL, but is this a dynamic record set connection ? Then it prolly does you select to get the record count and after another one to get the dynamic record set.

Comment: I dont use a lot the query syntax (prefer the lambda) so I can't completely make sense of this but I'm pretty sure you can make that a lot simplier by setting foreign keys and use navigation properties

Comment: It's one subquery, not a problem for performance. How would you prefer to have the SQL? You can compare your way with this way it shouldn't make a big difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example above shows a single query. The nested query does not impact performance if that is what you mean...

If you are working with a large set of data:
1) Make sure you have indexes on DutySavingFin.Month, MonthLookup.Month, and DutySavingFin.UserName+DutySavingFin.FirstName.
2) Add a where clause to filter down to the records you need, unless you *really* need all data in the table

Comment: There is a performance impact to nested query and normal one select query for huge data.

Comment: I have never seen that have an impact. Take a look at the execution plan for the L2S-generated query, and then try the same query flattened down without a subquery. Under normal circumstances, the SQL optimizer will generate the same execution plan.